# Fastest way to check for existence of a file in NodeJs

Tags: performance, node.js

I'm building a super simple server in node and in my onRequest listener I'm trying to determine if I should serve a static file (off the disk) or some json (probably pulled from mongo) based on the path in `request.url`.

Currently I'm trying to stat the file first (because I use mtime elsewhere) and if that doesn't fail then I read the contents from disk. Something like this:

```
fs.stat(request.url.pathname, function(err, stat) {
    if (!err) {
        fs.readFile(request.url.pathname, function( err, contents) {
            //serve file
        });
    }else {
        //either pull data from mongo or serve 404 error
    }
});
```

Other than cacheing the result of `fs.stat` for the `request.url.pathname`, is there something that could speed this check up? For example, would it be just as fast to see if `fs.readFile` errors out instead of the `stat`? Or using `fs.createReadStream` instead of `fs.readFile`? Or could I potentially check for the file using something in `child_process.spawn`? Basically I just want to make sure I'm not spending any extra time messing w/ fileio when the request should be sent to mongo for data...

Thanks!

Comment: I've always used `stat` or `statSync` depending on my needs (e.g. `statSync` in config), but I'd guess that it would technically be faster to do `readfile` and catch an error (though error catching is ___very___ heavy in JS, so I may be wrong).  In general, though, I'd prefer to use `stat` simply because it's cleaner than intentionally throwing an error.  Avoid `child_process` in general since `node` is making a push onto Windoze systems and any code using it will break.

Comment: @Lite Byte you should seriously accept the answer given by DeadDEnD...

Answer (score 58):

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.exists(file, function(exists) {
  if (exists) {
    // serve file
  } else {
    // mongodb
  }
});
```

Comment: Just FYI, `path.exists()` has been deprecated in later versions of Node. Now it's `fs.exists()`.

Comment: Please note that `file` can actually be a directory, symlink, pipe, etc. To only find files, you could use something like `fs.stat(file, function(err, stats) { if(!err && stats.isFile()) { //serve } else { //something else } });` But even that doesn't guarantee that you can actually read that file. Permissions might be wrong, or the file might just be removed before you actually read it. Depending on the context, one way to approach the problem might be to just try reading the file and then do something else if it fails.

Comment: from node docs: "fs.exists() is an anachronism and exists only for historical reasons. There should almost never be a reason to use it in your own code. fs.exists() will be deprecated." There are SOME legit reasons to use it, so what should it be replaced with?

Comment: It took me a while, but I think the correct pattern is to try and serve the static file first, then if that fails for some reason (file does not exist), you can fallback to other methods. That neatly avoids checking if the file exists.

Comment: Now `fs.exists()` is been deprecated. Use `fs.stat()` or `fs.access()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you should be worrying about that, but rather how can you improve the caching mechanism. `fs.stat` is really ok for file checking, doing that in another child process would probably slow you down rather then help you here.

Connect implemented the staticCache() middleware a few months ago, as described in this blog post: http://tjholowaychuk.com/post/9682643240/connect-1-7-0-fast-static-file-memory-cache-and-more

> A Least-Recently-Used (LRU) cache algo is implemented through the
>   `Cache` object, simply rotating cache objects as they are hit. This
>   means that increasingly popular objects maintain their positions while
>   others get shoved out of the stack and garbage collected.

Other resources: 
http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/middleware-staticCache.html 
[The source code for staticCache](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/staticCache.js)

Answer (score 2):

this snippet can help you

```
fs = require('fs') ;
var path = 'sth' ;
fs.stat(path, function(err, stat) {
    if (err) {
        if ('ENOENT' == err.code) {
            //file did'nt exist so for example send 404 to client
        } else {
            //it is a server error so for example send 500 to client
        }
    } else {
        //every thing was ok so for example you can read it and send it to client
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to serve a file using express, I would recommend to just use the sendFile error Handler of express

```
const app = require("express")();

const options = {};
options.root = process.cwd();

var sendFiles = function(res, files) {
  res.sendFile(files.shift(), options, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      console.log(files);
      if(files.length === 0) {
        res.status(err.status).end();
      } else {
        sendFiles(res, files)
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Image Sent");
    }
  });
};

app.get("/getPictures", function(req, res, next) {
  const files = [
    "file-does-not-exist.jpg",
    "file-does-not-exist-also.jpg",
    "file-exists.jpg",
    "file-does-not-exist.jpg"
  ];

  sendFiles(res, files);

});

app.listen(8080);
```

If the file is not existent then it will go to the error that sends it self.
I made a github repo here https://github.com/dmastag/ex_fs/blob/master/index.js