# Node.js, nodetuts tutorial - example code will run, timeout after a while,(Chunked HTTP encoding)

Tags: node.js

This is a node tutorial for a beginner. Why doesn't my code work? It's identical to his and I have tried workarounds without success. Please help if you can.

http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/2-webtail-nodejs-child-processes-and-http-chunked-encoding.html#video

In this tutorial, he writes a log/text file to the webpage located at localhost:4000, previous examples work (tutorial 1) however I can't get this to do anything at all, it runs and that's all.

Could anyone get this printing a file to the webpage please. :)
Thanks!

```
var http = require('http');
var spawn  = require('child_process').spawn;

http.createServer(function(request, response){

    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'
    });

    var tail_child = spawn('tail', ['-f', '/var/log/system.log']);

    request.connection.on('end', function(){
        tail_child.kill();
    });

    tail_child.stdout.on('data', function(data){
        console.log(data.toString());
        response.write(data);
    });

}).listen(4000);
```

I have tried the following and they are making no difference:

```
    console.log(data.toString());
    response.write(data);
    response.end();
```

and

```
    console.log(data.toString());
    response.end(data);
```

---

Edit after `MiguelSanchezGonzalez` answer:

I added `tail_child.stderr.pipe(process.stdout);` into the right place, and this is the response I am getting:

```
CreateProcessW: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

A file certainly does exist here, and I have also tested many different paths including text files in the same folder as the script (such as `'/test.txt'` for example. So maybe i'm wrong, i just assumed when it said file it was talking about my file.

---

Edit 2:
I also checked if the path exists (crudely built from here): [Fastest way to check for existence of a file in NodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782908/fastest-way-to-check-for-existence-of-a-file-in-nodejs) and it does say that the file indeed exists.

This code:

```
var file = path.normalize = ('var/log/system.log');

    fs.exists(file, function(exists){
        util.debug(exists ? "yep, its there":"nope");
    });

    console.log(file);
```

outputs this:

```
var/log/system.log
DEBUG: yep, its there
```

Comment: Is it possible that your code is running as a user who doesn't have read permission on the log file?

Comment: Actually that is a good point. I run cmd as administrator though. I'll check this when I get home.

Comment: @ebohlman, I run cmd as admin and this made no difference. Still doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hy Joseph, I recomend to you to change this line in your code to see what kind of error do you have

```
http.createServer(function(request, response){

    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'
    });

    var tail_child = spawn('tail', ['-f', '/var/log/system.log']);

    request.connection.on('end', function(){
        tail_child.kill();
    });

    tail_child.stdout.on('data', function(data){
        console.log(data.toString());
        response.write(data);
    });

    /* Add this line to see the error in your terminal */
    tail_child.stderr.pipe(process.stdout);

}).listen(4000);
```

This will show you the description of the error, maybe you don't have this file in your filesystem o you can't open it, try changing the path file to other that you know that exists and can open it.

Comment: Cheers, I updated the question, unfortunately i'm still stuck but it did lead me to try all different paths out although its not making a difference. This one is a bit beyond me. :( (all these files exist, I make dummy files full of text)

Comment: Hey, I have added some code to check for the file, to confirm node can find it, and its there. (see update 2). cheers.

Answer (score 2):

OK, i'm so new to this and it shows, thanks everyone for helping me I have now found the cause. I was stupid and did not mention i'm on windows, I thought this was irrelevant as I had no idea this code was making a external call to another program.

Yeah I know, stupid Joe, I thought tail was just a command within node and didn't think properly. This mess makes sense now.

`var tail_child = spawn('C:/cygwin/bin/tail.exe', ['-f', 'var/log/system.log']);`

This fixes everything, install cygwin and hardlink that binary!
This code was meant for a linux/unix environment I guess, so we just have to make do.

I was talking with the author of nodetuts, (Pedro) and I mentioned I was on a windows box, Bam it all made sense, the code makes more sense to me now too (I was searching for ages on node documentation for `-f` and couldn't find much. haha)

I should have put windows in the description of my environment.

Oh well.

Silly Joe.

Comment: Anyone reading this, this is the answer to fix this on windows, just make sure you adapt your code for windows. Just remember most code examples for node are written in Linux/Unix and not originally for windows, so they may be making calls to a commandline tool within a alien OS, beware!

Comment: Hi, I am just looking at this tutorial. How did it work for you with the 'var/log/system.log' file? Doesn't windows log everything to a 'C:/WINDOWS/system32/config/SysEvent.Evt' file that is viewed using the event viewer? Now, i understood the intent of the tutorial, but could not get it to work. Would appreciate any pointers