# How to guarantee non-existance of a file before creating?

Tags: node.js, fs

`fs.exists` is now deprecated for a decent reason that I should try to open a file and catch error to be sure nothing is possible to delete the file in between checking and opening. But if I need to create a new file instead of opening an existing file, how do I guarantee that there is no file before I try to create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You can however, create a new file *or* open an existing one if it exists:

```
fs.open("/path", "a+", function(err, data){ // open for reading and appending
    if(err) return handleError(err);
    // work with file here, if file does not exist it will be created
});
```

Alternatively, open it with `"ax+"` which will error if it already exists, letting you handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = fs.existsSync || function existsSync(filePath){
  try{
    fs.statSync(filePath);
  }catch(err){
    if(err.code == 'ENOENT') return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```

https://gist.github.com/FGRibreau/3323836

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31545073/2435443

```
fs = require('fs') ;
var path = 'sth' ;
fs.stat(path, function(err, stat) {
    if (err) {
        if ('ENOENT' == err.code) {
            //file did'nt exist so for example send 404 to client
        } else {
            //it is a server error so for example send 500 to client
        }
    } else {
        //every thing was ok so for example you can read it and send it to client
    }
} );
```